# Django ORM Performance Issues

Tags: django

I am looping over 13,000 in-memory city names and generating queries to filter for something. I've encountered something I cannot explain...

When the loop has a single line:

`cities = City.objects.filter(name__iexact=city)`

performance is almost **800 items/second**

When the loop measures the length of the returned set...

```
cities = City.objects.filter(name__iexact=city)
num_citles = len(cities)
```

performance drops to **8 items/second**

I can't explain where the performance degradation occurrs. Obviously, I'm missing something... Why would counting the number of items on an in-memory array that is always between 0 and 3 items reducing performance by a factor of x100?

Comment: probably because you have duplicated quiries, you can check that with the "django-debug-toolbar" for example. I to remove redundant quries you can use "values_list" or "prefetch_related". those are build in apis of the ORM read more about it here.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django querysets are lazy so `QuerySet.filter` does not actually evaluate the queryset i.e. run the queries in the database. When you run `len` function on it, it is evaluated and it will get all the items from database after running the filter only to get the count. Hence, the `count` is very slower.

You'll get a far better performance if you run `COUNT` on the database level:

```
num_cities = City.objects.filter(name__iexact=city).count()
```